# Vora Modeler View preview fails with com.sap.spark.vora.client.jdbc.VoraJdbcException

Tags: vora

I'm running Vora 1.3 on HDP 2.4.3 with Spark 1.6.2.

I've got two tables with data of the same schema, one table residing in a HANA database, another stored as CSV file in HDFS.

I created both tables in Vora using Zeppelin:

```
CREATE TABLE flights_2006 (Year int, Month_ int, DayofMonth int, DayOfWeek int, DepTime int, CRSDepTime int, ArrTime int, CRSArrTime int, UniqueCarrier string, FlightNum int, 
TailNum string, ActualElapsedTime int, CRSElapsedTime int, AirTime int, ArrDelay int, DepDelay int, Origin string, Dest string, Distance int, TaxiIn int, TaxiOut int,
Cancelled int, CancellationCode int, Diverted int, CarrierDelay int, WeatherDelay int, NASDelay int, SecurityDelay int, LateAircraftDelay int)
USING com.sap.spark.vora
OPTIONS (
files "/exch/flights_filtered/part-00000,/exch/flights_filtered/part-00001,/exch/flights_filtered/part-00002,/exch/flights_filtered/part-00003,/exch/flights_filtered/part-00004",
csvdelimiter ","
)
```

**Q1.** By the way, when is it going to be possible to supply just directory names, not list all files in a directory, when creating Vora tables from file sources? It's very impractical, as one cannot predict how many part-files are going to be in a directory.

```
CREATE TABLE flights_2007
USING com.sap.spark.hana
OPTIONS (
tablepath "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
dbschema "XXXXXXXXXX",
host "XXXXXXXXXXX",
instance "00",
user "XXXXXXXXXXX",
passwd "XXXXXXXXXX"
)
```

And I was able to produce a result from the table join for these two (business meaning of such join set aside):

```
select f7.MONTH, f7.DAYOFMONTH, f7.UNIQUECARRIER, f7.FLIGHTNUM, f7.YEAR, f7.DEPTIME, f6.year, f6.DepTime
from flights_2007 as f7 inner join flights_2006 as f6 
on f7.MONTH = f6.Month_ and f7.DAYOFMONTH = f6.DayofMonth and f7.UNIQUECARRIER = f6.UniqueCarrier and f7.FLIGHTNUM = f6.FlightNum
where f7.MONTH = 1 and f7.DAYOFMONTH = 2 and f7.UNIQUECARRIER = 'WN'
```

Then I tried to do the very same steps in Vora Modeler.

**Q2.** How comes that REGISTER TABLE in Zeppelin doesn't lead to tables being available in Vora Modeler?

So, I executed the same two table creation statements in Vora Modeler, using all capitals in table names, as I remember Vora has some issues with that earlier. Then created a Vora View as a join of the two tables with this condition:

```
FLIGHTS_2007.MONTH = FLIGHTS_2006.MONTH_ and 
FLIGHTS_2007.DAYOFMONTH = FLIGHTS_2007.DAYOFMONTH and 
FLIGHTS_2007.UNIQUECARRIER = FLIGHTS_2006.UNIQUECARRIER and 
FLIGHTS_2007.FLIGHTNUM = FLIGHTS_2006.FLIGHTNUM
```

.. and used the where-condition:

```
FLIGHTS_2007.MONTH = 1 and 
FLIGHTS_2007.DAYOFMONTH = 2 and 
FLIGHTS_2007.UNIQUECARRIER = 'WN'
```

Expected result for that View preview would be the same as for Zeppelin-based select. Actual result (first few lines of):

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 2165.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 2165.0 (TID 78743, eba165.extendtec.com.au): com.sap.spark.vora.client.jdbc.VoraJdbcException: [Vora [eba165.extendtec.com.au:34530.1615085]] Unknown error when executing SELECT "FLIGHTS_2006"."FLIGHTNUM", "FLIGHTS_2006"."DEPTIME", "FLIGHTS_2006"."UNIQUECARRIER", "FLIGHTS_2006"."MONTH_", "FLIGHTS_2006"."YEAR" FROM "FLIGHTS_2006": HL(9): Runtime error. (schema error: could not resolve column "FLIGHTS_2006"."YEAR" (sql parse error)) at com.sap.spark.vora.client.jdbc.VoraJdbcClient.liftedTree1$1(VoraJdbcClient.scala:210) at com.sap.spark.vora.client.jdbc.VoraJdbcClient.generateAutocloseableIteratorFromQuery(VoraJdbcClient.scala:187) at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$generateAutocloseableIteratorFromQuery$1.apply(VoraClient.scala:363) at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$generateAutocloseableIteratorFromQuery$1.apply(VoraClient.scala:363) at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient.handleExceptions(VoraClient.scala:775) at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient.generateAutocloseableIteratorFromQuery(VoraClient.scala:362) at com.sap.spark.vora.VoraRDD.compute(voraRDD.scala:54) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41) at
```

**Q3.** Did I do anything wrong in Vora Modeler? Or is it actually a bug?

Answer (score 1):

you mention that you used all caps for table names when running your CREATE statements. In my experience with the 1.3 Modeler, you must use all uppercase for your column names as well.

> > schema error: could not resolve column "FLIGHTS_2006"."YEAR"

For example, if you used "CREATE TABLE FLIGHTS_2006 (Year int, ...", try changing that to "CREATE TABLE FLIGHTS_2006 (YEAR int, ..."

Comment: Tried that, as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Q1, yes this is something are currently reviewing as a feature request.

Regarding your Q2, is your Zeppelin connected to the same Vora Thriftserver as your Vora Modeler (aka Vora Tools) ?

Regarding your Q3, the other reply from Ryan is correct, column names are also case sensetive in Vora 1.3

Comment: on Q2: I installed Zeppelin as per manual, but I don't see any parameter in the interpreter telling it to which thriftserver it should be connecting -- how can I check it? On Q3: Apparently I already created column names for FLIGHTS_2006 as all-capitals, too, as I just converted the whole create-statement to all-caps (except file and class names). I have recreated the Vora View, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Further to this, I remember the Modeler was displaying table/column names as capitals even when they had been created lowercase -- that seems like a Modeler bug, esp. that you're saying table/column names are case-sensitive.

Comment: On Q2: If you are using the %spark interpreter then you are using a different sqlContext than Vora Tools and therefore you must register tables separatly in each session. However the %jdbc interpreter connects to the Vora Thriftserver that is also used by the Vora Tools, here I would expect the same tables to be visible on each front-end tool.